# The value(s) of $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ is (are)?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> Let $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that
>   $f(\cos(4\theta))=\dfrac{2}{2-\sec^2(\theta)}$ for $\theta \in
>  (0,\pi/4) \cup (\pi/4,\pi/2)$. Then the value(s) of $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ is
>   (are) ?

**My Attempt:**

If $\cos(4\theta)=\dfrac{1}{3}$ then $1+\dfrac{1}{\cos(2\theta)}$ can be both $1+\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}$ and  $1-\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}$. However, as far as I know a function can only generate one value for one input. So which one should be the correct answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: We aren't told that the function *is* such and such.  We are told the function has a specific possibility.  If there are two possibiities for the values of $f(1/3)$ (I will take you word for it) we have no way of knowing which value it is.  We can all answer what possible values it *might* be and we must list them all.  Unless we are allowing for multivalued functions, which doesn't satisfy the conventional definition but is acceptable if specified, which this problem seems to do.